# Google Scripts randomly returns 0 after one loop

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm making this script to populate a sheets document with ~10000 points of unique data for use with a Neural Network. The issue being I'm somehow returning a 0 in the middle of the script when checking if the time is on a quarter of the hour or not. This only happens on the 4th loop through of the function, and It's starting to frustrate the hell out of me. code here:

```
function checkTimes(sT,eT,rT){
  sT = sT.toString();
  eT = eT.toString();
  startTime = sT;
  endTime = eT;
  if(sT[2] >= "6"){
    startTime = sT[0] + (Number(sT[1]) + 1).toString() + "00";
  }
  if(sT[0] >= "2" && sT[1] >= "5"){
    startTime = "1030";
    newDay = 1;
  }
  endTime = Number(startTime) + rT;
  if(eT[2] >= "6"){
   endTime = eT[0] + (Number(eT[1]) + 1).toString() + "00";
  }
  return [startTime, endTime];
}


// use .indexOf() function
function roundQuarter(sT,rT){
  sT = sT.toString();
  var quarterTimes = ['00','15','30','45'];
  var tempTimes = checkTimes(sT,rT);
  addUp = Number(tempTimes[0][2] + tempTimes[0][3]);
  subDown = Number(tempTimes[0][2] + tempTimes[0][3]);
  Logger.log("The current number is " + addUp);

  if(quarterTimes.indexOf(sT[2]+sT[3]) == -1){
    for(var i = 0; i <= 8; i++){
     addUp = addUp +1;
     Logger.log('Adding up... ' + addUp);
     subDown = subDown -1;
      Logger.log('Subtracting down... ' + subDown);
      if(quarterTimes.indexOf(addUp.toString()) != -1){
       return sT[0] + sT[1] + Number(addUp + 15); 
      }
      if(quarterTimes.indexOf(subDown.toString()) != -1){
       return sT[0] + sT[1] + Number(subDown + 30); 
      }
    }
  }else{
   return (Number(sT) + 15); 
  }
}


// Check Previous Endtime
// run roundQuarter to find nearest quarter hour
function incTimes(sT,eT,rT){
  Logger.log('Incrementing Times...');
  var timeTemp = checkTimes(sT,eT,rT);
  startTime = timeTemp[0];
  endTime = timeTemp[1];
  startTime = roundQuarter((sT + rT).toString(),rT);
  endTime = roundQuarter((eT + rT).toString(),rT);
  return [startTime, endTime];
}

function incTheatre(T){
  if(T == '9'){
   return '1' 
  }else{
   return (Number(T) + 1).toString(); 
  }
}


function calRandNum(isMajor,wsr){
  if(isMajor){
   mult = 100 
  }else{
   mult = 50 
  }
  multi = mult * (1 - (wsr/25));
 return Math.floor(Math.random() * multi)+1;
}


function mainFunc() {
  var startTime = "1030";
    var runTime = 200;
  var incremTimes = [1,2];
  var endTime = Number(startTime) + runTime;
  Logger.log(endTime + " Is the current end time.");
  var wsr = 0;

  var expectPop = '100';
  var actualPop = '110';
  var theatre = '1';
  var essenTheatres = ['1','4','5','9'];
  var nonEssenTheatres = ['2','3','6','7','8'];
  var days = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'];
  var currDay = days[0];
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1Rvv9tVn12JZpnn4lWfVHdgeOA_6wRlGt6JqdFY7sKCE');
  var data = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
  var appendedRow = ['Name','Publisher','Genre','Weeks Since Release','Day of Showing','Theatre','Start Time','End Time','Run Time','Presales','Actual Attendance'];
  var movieNames = [['Black Panther','Marvel','Action',wsr,currDay,theatre,startTime,endTime,215,expectPop,actualPop],['Infinity War','Marvel','Action',wsr,currDay,theatre,startTime,endTime,240,expectPop,actualPop],
                   ['Incredibles 2','Disney','Action',wsr,currDay,theatre,startTime,endTime,205,expectPop, actualPop],['Peter Rabbit','Sony','Fantasy',wsr,currDay,theatre,startTime,endTime,135,expectPop,actualPop],
                   ['Deathwish', 'MGM','Action',wsr,currDay,theatre,startTime,endTime,147,expectPop,actualPop],['A Quiet Place','Paramount','Thriller',wsr,currDay,theatre,startTime,endTime,131,expectPop,actualPop],
                    ['Ready Player One','Warner Bros','Action',wsr,currDay,theatre,startTime,endTime,219,expectPop,actualPop],['Pacific Rim: Uprising','Universal','Action',wsr,currDay,theatre,startTime,endTime,151,expectPop,actualPop]];
  var essenMovies = [movieNames[0],movieNames[1],movieNames[2],movieNames[6]];
  var nonEssenMovies = [movieNames[3],movieNames[4],movieNames[5],movieNames[7]];
  var timeArray = checkTimes(startTime,endTime,200);
  startTime = timeArray[0];
  endTime = timeArray[1];
  var quarter = roundQuarter('0020',runTime);
  Logger.log(quarter)
  Logger.log(startTime)
  Logger.log(endTime)
  var testTime = incTimes(1030, 1230, 200);
  Logger.log(testTime[0]);
  Logger.log(testTime[1]);
  var daysPassed = 0;
  var dayNum = 0;
  /*TODO:
  Check to see if day is reset **DONE**
  Increment week after 7 days
  Check for all theatres to be assigned
  Use movieNames array for end time
  */
  for(var i = 0;i < 1; i++){
    if(dayNum == days.length -1){
     wsr = wsr + 1;
     dayNum = 0
    }
    currDay = days[dayNum];
    if(essenTheatres.indexOf(theatre) != -1){
      for(var i = 0; i < essenMovies.length; i++){
        if(i == 2){
         startTime = startTime + 15;
        }
        timeArray = checkTimes(startTime, endTime, essenMovies[i][8]);
        startTime = timeArray[0];
        endTime = timeArray[1];
        incremTimes = incTimes(startTime, endTime, essenMovies[i][8]);
       ss.appendRow(essenMovies[i]);
        theatre = incTheatre(theatre);
        startTime = incremTimes[0];
        endTime = incremTimes[1];
      }
    }
    if(nonEssenMovies.indexOf(theatre) != -1){
      for(var i = 0; i < nonEssenMovies.length; i++){
        if(i == 2 || i == 4){
         startTime = startTime + 15; 
        }
        timeArray = checkTimes(startTime, endTime, nonEssenMovies[i][8]);
        startTime = timeArray[0];
        endTime = timeArray[1];
        incremTimes = incTimes(startTime, endTime, nonEssenMovies[i][8]);
        ss.appendRow(nonEssenMovies[i]);
        if(theatre == '9'){
         runTime = nonEssenMovies[i][8]; 
        }
        startTime = incremTimes[0];
        endTime = incremTimes[1];
        theatre = incTheatre(theatre);

      }

    }
    var newTimes = incTimes(startTime, endTime, runTime);
    }
  }
```

Log here:

```
[18-07-24 01:16:40:598 EDT] 1230 Is the current end time.
[18-07-24 01:16:40:852 EDT] The current number is 20
[18-07-24 01:16:40:852 EDT] Adding up... 21
[18-07-24 01:16:40:853 EDT] Subtracting down... 19
[18-07-24 01:16:40:853 EDT] Adding up... 22
[18-07-24 01:16:40:854 EDT] Subtracting down... 18
[18-07-24 01:16:40:854 EDT] Adding up... 23
[18-07-24 01:16:40:855 EDT] Subtracting down... 17
[18-07-24 01:16:40:855 EDT] Adding up... 24
[18-07-24 01:16:40:855 EDT] Subtracting down... 16
[18-07-24 01:16:40:856 EDT] Adding up... 25
[18-07-24 01:16:40:856 EDT] Subtracting down... 15
[18-07-24 01:16:40:857 EDT] 0045
[18-07-24 01:16:40:857 EDT] 1030
[18-07-24 01:16:40:858 EDT] 1230.0
[18-07-24 01:16:40:858 EDT] Incrementing Times...
[18-07-24 01:16:40:859 EDT] The current number is 30
[18-07-24 01:16:40:860 EDT] The current number is 30
[18-07-24 01:16:40:860 EDT] 1430
[18-07-24 01:16:40:861 EDT] 1445.0
[18-07-24 01:16:40:861 EDT] Incrementing Times...
[18-07-24 01:16:40:862 EDT] The current number is 30
[18-07-24 01:16:40:863 EDT] The current number is 0
[18-07-24 01:16:40:863 EDT] Adding up... 1
[18-07-24 01:16:40:864 EDT] Subtracting down... -1
[18-07-24 01:16:40:864 EDT] Adding up... 2
[18-07-24 01:16:40:865 EDT] Subtracting down... -2
[18-07-24 01:16:40:865 EDT] Adding up... 3
[18-07-24 01:16:40:866 EDT] Subtracting down... -3
[18-07-24 01:16:40:866 EDT] Adding up... 4
[18-07-24 01:16:40:867 EDT] Subtracting down... -4
[18-07-24 01:16:40:867 EDT] Adding up... 5
[18-07-24 01:16:40:867 EDT] Subtracting down... -5
[18-07-24 01:16:40:868 EDT] Adding up... 6
[18-07-24 01:16:40:868 EDT] Subtracting down... -6
[18-07-24 01:16:40:869 EDT] Adding up... 7
[18-07-24 01:16:40:869 EDT] Subtracting down... -7
[18-07-24 01:16:40:870 EDT] Adding up... 8
[18-07-24 01:16:40:870 EDT] Subtracting down... -8
[18-07-24 01:16:40:871 EDT] Adding up... 9
[18-07-24 01:16:40:871 EDT] Subtracting down... -9
```

It's saying the error is happening on line 3, where eT is undefined. Anyone have any ideas?